Multivariate polynomial multiplication for high degree of freedom
I'm trying to find a way to multiply high degree of freedom polynomials (~100 variables). The degree of the polynomials is usually low, 2 or 3. I have built the following code that does exactly the job but is highly inefficient:
Variables -> seconds
20 -> 6
30 -> 20
40 -> 69
50 -> 215
Ideally this should be way under the second because it has to be applied multiple times. Does anyone know any suggestion/algorithm more suitable for this task?
import math
from time import time

def generate_combinations(n, m, current_combo=None):
    if current_combo is None:
        current_combo = []

    if len(current_combo) == n:
        if sum(current_combo) == m:
            yield tuple(current_combo)
        return

    # Calculate the sum so far to determine the maximum possible value for the next element
    current_sum = sum(current_combo)
    remaining_sum = m - current_sum

    # Generate the next element, starting from the remaining sum down to 0
    for i in range(remaining_sum, -1, -1):
        new_combo = current_combo + [i]
        yield from generate_combinations(n, m, new_combo)

def create_hierarchical_dict(depth):
    if depth == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return {0: create_hierarchical_dict(depth - 1)}

def access_dict_with_tuple(d, keys, value=None):
    try:
        if value==None:
            if len(keys) == 0:
                return d
            else:
                return access_dict_with_tuple(d[keys[0]], keys[1:])
        else:
            if len(keys) == 0:
                return value
            elif keys[0] in d:
                d[keys[0]] = access_dict_with_tuple(d[keys[0]], keys[1:], value)
                return d
            else:
                if len(keys) == 1:
                    d[keys[0]] = value
                    return d
                else:
                    d[keys[0]] = access_dict_with_tuple({}, keys[1:], value)
                    return d
    except KeyError:
        return 0.0

def poly(m, order, coeff):
    # Example usage
    poly = create_hierarchical_dict(m)
    i = 0
    for d in range(order + 1):
        for combo in generate_combinations(m, d):
            if coeff[i] != 0:
                access_dict_with_tuple(poly, combo, coeff[i])
            i+=1
    return poly

def print_poly(m, order, coeff, title=''):
    # Example usage
    out = []
    for d in range(order + 1):
        for combo in generate_combinations(m, d):
            c = access_dict_with_tuple(coeff, combo)
            if c != 0:
                literal = [f"x_{i}**{exp}" if exp > 1 else f"x_{i}" for i,exp in enumerate(combo) if exp != 0]
                out.append(f"{c} * " + "*".join(literal))
    print(title + " + ".join(out))

def access_to_idx(polynomial, idx=[]):
    for key, value in polynomial.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from access_to_idx(value, idx + [key])
        else:
            yield idx + [key]

def sum_polynomials(polynomial1, polynomial2):
    result = polynomial1
    # Example usage
    for combo_target in access_to_idx(polynomial2):
        coeff1 = access_dict_with_tuple(polynomial1, combo_target)
        coeff2 = access_dict_with_tuple(polynomial2, combo_target)
        coeff_target = coeff1 + coeff2

        result = access_dict_with_tuple(result, combo_target, coeff_target)

    return result

def dict_depth(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return 0
    else:
        depths = [dict_depth(v) for v in d.values()]
        return 1 + max(depths, default=0)

def multiply_polynomials(polynomial1, polynomial2):
    depth = dict_depth(polynomial1)
    result = create_hierarchical_dict(depth)
    # Example usage
    for combo1 in access_to_idx(polynomial1):
        for combo2 in access_to_idx(polynomial2):
            coeff1 = access_dict_with_tuple(polynomial1, combo1)
            coeff2 = access_dict_with_tuple(polynomial2, combo2)
            combo_target = [c1+c2 for c1,c2 in zip(combo1,combo2)]
            coeff_target = coeff1 * coeff2 + access_dict_with_tuple(result, combo_target)

            if coeff_target != 0:
                result = access_dict_with_tuple(result, combo_target, coeff_target)
    return result

print('Polynomials:')
m1 = 50
order1 = 2
coeff1 = list(range(sum([math.comb(m1+d-1, d) for d in range(order1+1)])))
# coeff1 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
title1 = 'f = '

m2 = m1
order2 = order1
coeff2 = [2*c for c in coeff1]
# coeff2 = [0, -1.5, 0, -2, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
title2 = 'g = '

polynomial1 = poly(m1, order1, coeff1)
print_poly(m1, order1, polynomial1, title1)
polynomial2 = poly(m2, order2, coeff2)  
print_poly(m2, order2, polynomial2, title2)


print('Sum of polynomials:')
summation = sum_polynomials(polynomial1, polynomial2)

print_poly(m1, max(order1,order2), summation, 'f + g = ')


print('Product of polynomials:')
a = time()
product = multiply_polynomials(polynomial1, polynomial2)
b = time()

# print_poly(m1, order1 + order2, product, 'f * g = ')

print('Time:', b-a)

```

